# vertx executeBlocking different behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, vert.x

I was experimenting with vertx executeBlocking, to simulate a real time scenario I did following

```
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id ->{
    counter += 1;
    LOGGER.info("invoked method {} ",counter);
    vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
        int counterFinal = counter;
        String result = service.blockingMethod("cycle "+counterFinal+" executed");
        future.complete(result);
    }, res -> {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("The result is: %s", res.result()));
    });
```

the blocking method is pretty straight forward

```
public String blockingMethod(String result){
    block(2);
    return result;
}
```

And this was the outcome

```
07:50:27.742 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 1 
07:50:28.742 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 2 
07:50:29.740 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 3 
07:50:29.764 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - The result is: cycle 1 executed
07:50:30.739 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 4 
07:50:31.739 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 5 
07:50:31.773 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - The result is: cycle 3 executed
07:50:32.751 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 6 
07:50:33.748 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - invoked method 7 
07:50:33.789 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.AsyncExperimentalVerticle - The result is: cycle 5 executed
```

it is clearly missing two events on average because the delay was set to 2 seconds.
Then I wrapped the blocking method inside a class and then executed in following manner

```
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, id ->{
    counter++;
    LOGGER.info("invoked method {} ",counter);
    service.wrapperMethod("Hello", counter, new Handler<AsyncClass>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(AsyncClass event) {
            vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                String result = event.result();
                future.complete(result);
            }, res -> {
                LOGGER.info(String.format("The result is: %s", res.result()));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and the wrapper Method was designed in this way

```
public void wrapperMethod(String input, int cycle, Handler<AsyncClass> execute) {
    AsyncClass instance = new AsyncClass(input,String.valueOf(cycle)); // my custom class where the result method has a 2 sec delay
    execute.handle(instance);
}
```

then I got the expected result.

```
08:08:27.358 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 1 
08:08:27.368 [vert.x-worker-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.support.AsyncClass - Invoking method inside AsyncClass class
08:08:28.338 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 2 
08:08:29.345 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 3 
08:08:29.384 [vert.x-worker-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.support.AsyncClass - Invoking method inside AsyncClass class
08:08:29.386 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - The result is: Hello world of cycle 1
08:08:30.347 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 4 
08:08:31.351 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 5 
08:08:31.391 [vert.x-worker-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.support.AsyncClass - Invoking method inside AsyncClass class
08:08:31.391 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - The result is: Hello world of cycle 2
08:08:32.341 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 6 
08:08:33.343 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - invoked method 7 
08:08:33.396 [vert.x-worker-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.support.AsyncClass - Invoking method inside AsyncClass class
08:08:33.397 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] INFO lab.async.base.verticle.TestVerticle2 - The result is: Hello world of cycle 3
```

Now I am seeing the asynchronous execution without missing a single event. I can't find a possible explanation.
Even in wrapper Method if I give a delay of n seconds it will miss events as expected.

Someone please help me to understand this behaviour.

update1:

for second scenario the structure of `AsyncClass` is given below

```
public class AsyncClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncClass.class);

    private String input;
    private String cycle;

    public AsyncClass(String input, String cycle) {
        this.input = input;
        this.cycle = cycle;
    }

    public String result(){
        LOGGER.info("Invoking method inside AsyncClass class");
        block(2);
        return input+" world of cycle "+cycle;
    }

    private void block(int pauseLimitInSecond){
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(pauseLimitInSecond);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            LOGGER.error("exception - > ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is *Invoking method inside AsyncClass class* message logged?

Comment: the actual blocking method `fun result()` for the 2nd case is inside `AsyncClass`. I have updated my question with more details. please see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behavior is due to [*Lambda body variable capture*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) where the outer class reference (`this`) is captured.

The outer class instance variable `counter` will have its value changed when the *Lambda body* expression will be evaluated (incremented by `1` over the initial value) which gives the illusion of an unexpected behavior.

Keeping the same program sequence, you can replace the *Lambda expression* body by an `Handler<Future<String>>` implementation where the `counter` outer instance variable is stored in another instance variable which will be used in the handler execution body:

```java
private static final class BlockingHandler implements Handler<Future<String>> {

    private final YourBlockingService service;

    private final int counter;

    public BlockingHandler(int counter, YourBlockingService service) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Future<String> event) {
        String result = service.blockingMethod("cycle " + this.counter + " executed", 2);
        event.complete(result);
    }
}
```

Your verticle code would then look as follows:

```java
this.vertx.setPeriodic(
      1000,
      id -> {
          counter += 1;
          LOGGER.info("invoked method {}", counter);
          vertx.executeBlocking(
                new YourBlockingHandler(this.counter, this.service),
                res -> LOGGER.info(String.format("The result is: %s", res.result()))
          );
      }
);
```

To resume, the mentioned behavior only relates to the closure semantics and has nothing to do with *Vert.x* internals.

Answer (score 1):

The `executeBlocking` [method](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#executeBlocking-io.vertx.core.Handler-io.vertx.core.Handler-) you use ensures that blocking tasks are executed in order (one after the other).

So when the second blocking task is executed (after two seconds), the `counter` variable has already been incremented twice. Hence the `1`, `3`, `5` series.

In your other attempt with a wrapping class, the `counter` variable value is captured before `executeBlocking` is invoked. So when the blocking task is executed, you get the value you expect.